# How to alter a button's label animations from multiple view in my project?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

I have a SwiftUI button in one of my views.  For the label I use two different SF Symbols with different colors and animations based on the value of a var "gpsIsActive"

Here is a video:

[image]

The button works fine.  **But** I need to trigger these same color and animation changes in multiple views across multiple files.  **How do I do this⁉️**

I have tried making a public function that returned "some View" and all it did was return the Image.  Everywhere I called this function I received warning that I was not using the returned result (because I simply wanted to trigger the changes).

Now I need to call this from another file and **the fact that it is a function that returns a View is causing further problems**.

The answer may be something related to `@State` & `@Binding` but I can't figure it out. Please help! LOL

### The Original Button...

```swift
Button {
    daFellowBeenTapped()
 } label: {
    Image(systemName: gpsIsActive ? "figure.run.circle" :"figure.wave.circle")
       .contentTransition(.symbolEffect(.replace.downUp))
       .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
       .foregroundStyle(personColor, circleColor)
       .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
       .frame(width: Constants.roundedViewL, height: Constants.roundRectViewH)
       .foregroundColor(.clear)
       .background(Color(.clear))
       .clipShape(Circle())
       .symbolEffect(gpsIsActive ? .bounce.up.byLayer : .bounce.down.byLayer, 
            options: gpsIsActive ? .speed(0.0).repeating : .nonRepeating, value: gpsIsActive)

 }
 .frame(height: 56)
```

### The Button with Function (causing problems elsewhere)...

```swift
 Button {
    daFellowBeenTapped()
 } label: {
    daButtonPretty()
 }
```

```swift
public func daButtonPretty() -> some View {
   return Image(systemName: gpsMonitoringIsActive ? "figure.run.circle" :  "figure.wave.circle")
      .contentTransition(.symbolEffect(.replace.downUp))
      .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
      .foregroundStyle(personColor, circleColor)
      .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
      .frame(width: Constants.General.roundedViewLength, height: Constants.General.roundRectViewHeight)
      .foregroundColor(.clear)
      .background(Color(.clear))
      .clipShape(Circle())
      .symbolEffect(gpsMonitoringIsActive ? .bounce.up.byLayer : .bounce.down.byLayer, options: gpsMonitoringIsActive ? .speed(0.0).repeating : .nonRepeating, value: gpsMonitoringIsActive)
}
```

Comment: It isn’t clear what you are trying to accomplish and how you are trying to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to encapsulate the state information in a model and then pass the model to the views that need to use it.

- You could either do this by using a `struct` which is held as a `State` variable in the parent view and passed as a `Binding` to the child views
- or, you could use an `ObservableObject`, which is held as a `StateObject` in the parent view and observed as an `ObservedObject` in the child views.

Here is an example of the latter approach:

```swift
class ActiveInfo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isActive: Bool

    init(isActive: Bool) {
        self.isActive = isActive
    }

    var color: Color {
        isActive ? Color.green : Color.red
    }

    func toggle() {
        isActive.toggle()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var activeInfo = ActiveInfo(isActive: false)

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 50) {
            Text(activeInfo.isActive ? "ACTIVE" : "INACTIVE")
            DaFellowButton(activeInfo: activeInfo)
            Button("Toggle") {
                activeInfo.toggle()
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .tint(activeInfo.color)
        }
    }
}

struct DaFellowButton: View {

    @ObservedObject var activeInfo: ActiveInfo
    let circleColor = Color.blue

    private func daFellowBeenTapped() {
        activeInfo.toggle()
    }

    private var gpsIsActive: Bool {
        activeInfo.isActive
    }

    private var personColor: Color {
        activeInfo.color
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            daFellowBeenTapped()
         } label: {
            Image(systemName: gpsIsActive ? "figure.run.circle" :"figure.wave.circle")
               .contentTransition(.symbolEffect(.replace.downUp))
               .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
               .foregroundStyle(personColor, circleColor)
               .font(.system(size: 50, weight: .thin))
               .frame(width: Constants.roundedViewL, height: Constants.roundRectViewH)
               .foregroundColor(.clear)
               .background(Color(.clear))
               .clipShape(Circle())
               .symbolEffect(gpsIsActive ? .bounce.up.byLayer : .bounce.down.byLayer,
                    options: gpsIsActive ? .speed(0.0).repeating : .nonRepeating, value: gpsIsActive)

         }
         .frame(height: 56)
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: @20386264 … THANK YOU‼️  Your solution is much better than the hack that I came up with.  :-)